# NA_integer as a result of a sum

Tags: sum, integer

I need some help with a mystery that I'm dealing with. Sorry if it is a beginner question , but I'm just starting to work with R.

I'm doing a work of analyzing coronavirus cases in the world using the coronavirus package.
By the time I try to establish the total registered cases, the value that I get from this new data subset is always NA_int. I honestly don't know how to get out of this situation. Look at the codes I've made so far:

```
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(readr, ggplot2, dplyr, coronavirus, knitr)

total_cases <- coronavirus_dataset %>% 
  group_by(type, date) %>%
  summarise(diary_cases = sum(cases)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(full_cases = cumsum(diary_cases))

**total_cases_all = sum(coronavirus_dataset$cases)** ==> here is the problem as the 
total_cases_all appears in the environment as NA_integer

percent_cases <- coronavirus_dataset %>% 
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(total_cases = sum(cases)) %>% 
  mutate(percent_total = round(total_cases / total_cases_all  * 100, digits = 2)) 
%>% 
  arrange(desc(total_cases))
```

Thanks in advance.